# How to check if the files exists from inside a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7

I have several files like thes......

```
runtime/common/pc.layoutconfig/0001CD145AAD5339EDEDC1616C8D5077.pc_resourcelib
runtime/common/pc.layoutconfig/01BFFBA4B3000403D29349625F993A88.pc_resourcelib
runtime/common/pc.layoutconfig/049ABD868C8E7CC1DFDC36E5BD8D9E25.pc_resourcelib
runtime/common/pc.layoutconfig/059397634EF0CE9D71377A755AE4596F.pc_resourcelib
runtime/common/pc.layoutconfig/06064545A76229EFA8F5D1D3B3D5DCAD.pc_resourcelib
runtime/common/pc.layoutconfig/08CAA66FDD0D86AD2EA16CDA675F9C66.pc_resourcelib
runtime/common/pc.layoutconfig/09ACF6E792AD02AB4B47BDF7E069E7DF.pc_resourcelib
runtime/common/pc.layoutconfig/0AC5B504AEE3B861A0BAA6046B0BA788.pc_resourcelib
```

Now if i want to check is wheter these files exists or not and show the name of files those **do not exists** in win7 how can i do this programaticaly ?

```
runtime/common/pc.layoutconfig/0001CD145AAD5339EDEDC1616C8D5077.pc_resourcelib
runtime/common/pc.layoutconfig/01BFFBA4B3000403D29349625F993A88.pc_resourcelib
runtime/common/pc.layoutconfig/049ABD868C8E7CC1DFDC36E5BD8D9E25.pc_resourcelib
runtime/common/pc.layoutconfig/059397634EF0CE9D71377A755AE4596F.pc_resourcelib
```

I can check one file at a time but how do i check several ?

Comment: show files, that do not exist? How to know? Is there a file with filenames, that **should** be there?

Comment: if this `runtime/common/pc.layoutconfig/059397634EF0CE9D71377A755AE4596F.pc_resourcelib` does not exits output a message or print it simply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for %%a in (
"runtime\common\pc.layoutconfig\0001CD145AAD5339EDEDC1616C8D5077.pc_resourcelib"
"runtime\common\pc.layoutconfig\01BFFBA4B3000403D29349625F993A88.pc_resourcelib"
"runtime\common\pc.layoutconfig\049ABD868C8E7CC1DFDC36E5BD8D9E25.pc_resourcelib"
... [and so on...]
) do if not exist "%%~a" echo "%%~a" does not exist
```

- of course, there's a simpler solution if these names are in a file, but you don't tell us how you are obtaining them.

Also note that `\` is a directory-separator, `/` is a switch designator.

And this assumes that the desired target file exists or no with respect to the current directory.

And it's written as a series of lines within a batch file. Executing directly from the prompt is different.

Comment: the for loop will contain the `filenames` i want to search or the `filenames` inside the directory i want to search ?

Comment: @user3508453 You can use either.  If the current directory contains the files then you only need the filenames.

Answer (score 1):

i changed Magoo's answer a little;

```
set /p asd=Enter Your File Name
for /F  "tokens=*" %%a in (%asd%) DO (
  if not exist "%%~a" echo "%%~a" does not exist
)
```

and ofc just like Magoo said \ is a directory-separator.